# Path coverage testing: Basic logic

Tags: java, testing

I am trying to understand Path coverage completely and I have a question:

Let's say I have this program:

```
for (int i = 0; i <array.length;i++) {

      if (...) //1
     {
       //do sth

       return false;
     }

     if(...) //2
     {
            if(...) //2A
            {
             //Do sth
            }
            else () //2B
            {
               if (...) //2BX
               {
                  //Do sth
               }
               else  //2BY
               {
                  //Do sth
               }
          }
     else //3
     {
        //Do sth
     }
}
return true;
```

Is showing that,  given an array of inputs, each code (do sths) in `1,2A,2BX,2BY,3` is executed enough to satisfy path coverage testing?

A single input `array[i]` can only execute the code in only one of these `(1,2A,2BX,2BY,3)`

Or does the permutation of these `//do somethings` matter because there is a `for` loop in the program?

I am a little confused behind the logic behind it.

Thanks!

Comment: if you pass to your code `1,2A,2BX,2BY,3` always will be executed only first if statement and `false` will be returned.  So you can make 2 testcases. First - when the array contains value for statement 1, second - with values for other statements. If you want to verify, that all branches are covered by tests - you can use cobertura for example. http://cobertura.github.io/cobertura/

Comment: @DanilaZharenkov That's what I was planning!! But two test cases, first one executing the statement 1 and the second one executing rest of the 4 is enough for path coverage right ?? Existence of for loop doesn't mean anything in this case?

Comment: if input array of the second testcase will contain all values for statements - 2,2A.....3 - that should be enough. The loop helps you, cause you can write 1 testcase to cover several branches.